# Using large hash tables in R

Tags: r, hash, hashtable

I'm trying to use package `hash`, which I understand is the most commonly adopted implementation (other than directly using environments).

If I try to create and store hashes larger than ~20MB, I start getting `protect(): protection stack overflow` errors.

```
pryr::object_size(hash::hash(1:120000, 1:120000))  # * (see end of post)
#> 21.5 MB
h <- hash::hash(1:120000, 1:120000)
#> Error: protect(): protection stack overflow
```

If I run the `h <- ...` command once, the error only appears once. If I run it twice, I get an infinite loop of errors appearing in the console, freezing Rstudio and forcing me to restart it from the Task Manager.

From multiple other SO questions, I understand this means I'm creating more pointers than R can protect. This makes sense to me, since hashes are actually just environments (which themselves are just hash tables), so I assume R needs to keep track of each value in the hash table as a separate pointer.

The common solution I've seen for the `protect()` error is to use `rstudio.exe --max-ppsize=500000` (which I assume propagates that option to R itself), but it doesn't help in this case, the error remains. This is somewhat surprising, since the hash in the example above is only 120,000 keys/pointers long, much smaller than the given `ppsize` of 500,000.

So, how can I use large hashes in R? I'm assuming changing to pure environments won't help, since `hash` is really just a wrapper around environments.

---

* For the record, the given hash::hash() call above will create hashes with non-syntactic names, but that's irrelevant: my real case has simple character keys and integer values and shows the same behavior)

Comment: That looks like a bug or inefficient code somewhere, but I can't reproduce it.   (The protection stack doesn't need to hold all those pointers once they're in an environment.  Conceivably they're all being protected before insertion; that's a really inefficient way to do it.)  However, when I run your code I get no error.  Can you give a reproducible example that fails in a clean new session?

Comment: Correction:  I do get that error in RStudio, but not in standalone R.  It looks like an RStudio bug, when it tries to examine the object for display in the environment pane.

Comment: Already on their bug list:  https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/5546

Comment: @user2554330 Good catch, and I see you (or someone else) already commented on the issue with this use-case as well. Many thanks.

Comment: @user2554330 Feel free to write a brief answer with what you've posted here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in RStudio, not a limitation in R.  The bug happens when it tries to examine the `h` object for display in the environment pane.  The bug is on their issue list as https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/5546 .